# Jquery not data selector

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector

This works

```
  $('[data-department='+dept+']').closest('.person').hide();
```

So would expect this to show/hide the unselected elements.

```
$('[data-department !='+dept+']').closest('.person').hide();
```

It does not work as expected. Even when hard-coded.

```
$('[data-department!=8]').closest('.person').hide();
```

Comment: Use filter() instead of a data selector, which will result in a dom scan.  Otherwise you could try using :not([...])

Comment: `$('[data-department !='+dept+']')` will match many elements even the ones which don't have any `data-department` attribute... e.g `html, body, etc...` You'd have better to filter it using: `$('[data-department]').filter('[data-department !='+dept+']').closest(...)`

Comment: Let me restate the data selector warning.  Regardless of if you use filter or not, doing simply $('[...]') should be avoided due to performance issues.  Using purely attribute selectors, the browser has no way to scope the elements it needs to evaluate down and will check them all.  This is the majority of the time unnecessary work.  Which is why if you are going to use attribute selectors you should reduce the scope first so that the browser is only performing the comparison on as small of a subset as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('[data-department !='+dept+']')` will select the elements even those which doesn't have any `data-department` attribute as **A. Wolff** said. So you can use `filter()` method like following.

```js
$('[data-department]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('department') != 8;
}).closest('.person').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="person">
    <div data-department="8">
      8888888888888888
    </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div data-department="9">
      9999999999999999
    </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div data-department="10">
      1010101010101010
    </div>
</div>
```